# Translation facility in Phalcon

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual, phalcon

Does Phalcon provide any facility for multilingual web sites?

What is best practice for developing an MVC phalcon based site? How should I implement view layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sample application (https://github.com/phalcon/php-site) implements translation using Phalcon.

Comment: How can I use gettext in Phalcon architecture?

Comment: Let me create an example for you

Comment: However, remember that gettext isn't thread safe, if you're running the application with Apache you may have problems

Comment: Thanks, Most *nix do not use thread safe version of PHP, what problem do you mean? I am eagerly waiting for your promised example! :)

Comment: how do i use this class Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray with the volt templating system ? how do i access it ? i.e {% $t->('home') %} ??

Answer (score 2):

Phalcon does not offer I18n functionality. There is a PECL extension that offers this kind of functionality, called [intl](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) (see [manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/intl.html)).

However, if you are mostly interested in presenting the website in different languages, you can use the

```
\Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray
```

component. This component uses an array of key/values that contain the language aware strings. For instance you can use this in your config:

```
$trans_config = array(
                    'en' => array(
                        'bye'       => 'Good Bye',
                        'song-key'  => 'This song is %song% (%artist%)',
                    ),
                    'es' => array(
                        'bye'       => 'Adiós',
                        'song-key'  => 'La canción es %song% (%artist%)',
                    ),
                );
```

A test to demonstrate the above usage is:

```
public function testVariableSubstitutionTwoEnglish()
{
    $language   = $trans_config['en'];
    $params     = array('content' => $language);
    $translator = new \Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray($params);

    $vars     = array(
        'song'   => 'Dust in the wind',
        'artist' => 'Kansas',
    );
    $expected = 'This song is Dust in the wind (Kansas)';
    $actual   = $translator->_('song-key', $vars);

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expected,
        $actual,
        'Translator does not translate English correctly - many parameters'
    );
}
```

The above just shows how you can get translated messages with placeholder variables. To simply get a string in a different language, you just call the `_()` on the translator with the relevant key and no variables passed.

*EDIT* In the view you can work as you like. You can set variables that are displayed in the view layer or pass the translating object and perform the translation there. Up to you.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, What other adapter do you plan to implement? Creating and using such arrays is a little wordy, also it was better if `_('x',array('1','2'))` could be used in addition to `_('x',array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2'))`. Is it a good job to create a service namee `t` to be accessed via views?

Comment: What is pros and cons of using `\Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray` instead of Gettext?

Comment: Re Gettext very small, mostly performance and preference based. Performance actually is not a huge issue.

Comment: There is no such service (yet) but can definitely be addressed later on. At the moment you can just grab the array and assign it in a view variable, and then access it in the view.

Comment: I believe I heard that there will be at some point a PO adapter but not sure there. This particular question could be answered better by the developers/community.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use [Phalcon Gettext Adapter](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Translate/Adapter). The most important advantage of Gettext is handling plurals.